# How to check whether the contact is phone contact or not?

Tags: android, contacts

I have one arrayList of type object which have two kind of contacts, one is app contacts and another is phone contacts...I need to hide one particular button based on the result.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this:

```
if (items.elementAt(0) instanceof PhoneContact) {  //for example if the name of your class is PhoneContact
   //do something
} else if (items.elementAt(0) instanceof AppContact){  //if your class name is AppContact
    //do something else
}
```

Comment: I have same activity for both

Comment: I am trying with ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME but it's giving all the contacts.

Comment: and how do you make the difference between your AppContacts and the phone contacts? don't you have any Contact class for your users?

Comment: Thanks Gabriella..I got the solution, now i am creating seprate classes for each type.